Interceptor doesn't activate and set the header in Angular 18
My interceptor doesn't work in Angular version 18. The backend says it can't add the header to the request:
Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-09-29T12:39:52.861+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-09-29T12:39:52.861+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-29T12:39:52.861+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-09-29T12:39:53.031+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /posts/all
2024-09-29T12:39:53.046+02:00  WARN 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.antonsteve96.ngrx.security.JwtFilter   : Authorization header missing or does not start with 'Bearer '
2024-09-29T12:39:53.046+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-29T12:39:53.046+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /posts/all
2024-09-29T12:39:53.047+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.antonsteve96.ngrx.post.PostController.getAllPosts(); target is of class [com.antonsteve96.ngrx.post.PostController]
2024-09-29T12:39:53.047+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.antonsteve96.ngrx.post.PostController.getAllPosts(); target is of class [com.antonsteve96.ngrx.post.PostController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.authorization.method.PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager@632fe645 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=isAuthenticated()]
2024-09-29T12:39:53.047+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-09-29T12:39:53.048+02:00 DEBUG 14733 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error

I expect that Angular that is the frontend can add the header to the request and not make the http call fail. I'm trying to implement a feature with JWT token that allows the user to reach certain endpoint only if is logged in. To do that I need the interceptor to be working:
import {ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom, isDevMode, provideZoneChangeDetection} from "@angular/core";
import {provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
import {routes} from "./app.routes";
import {provideClientHydration} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, provideHttpClient, withFetch} from "@angular/common/http";
import {StoreModule} from "@ngrx/store";
import {EffectsModule} from "@ngrx/effects";
import {AuthEffects} from "./auth/state/auth.effects";
import {provideStoreDevtools} from "@ngrx/store-devtools";
import {AuthService} from './services/auth.service';
import {counterReducer} from "./counter/state/counter.reducer";
import {COUNTER_STATE} from "./counter/state/counter.state";
import {POSTS_STATE} from "./posts/state/posts.state";
import {postsReducer} from "./posts/state/posts.reducer";
import {rootReducer} from "./store/root.state";
import {AuthInterceptor} from "./services/auth.interceptor";
import {PostsEffects} from "./posts/state/posts.effects";
import {PostsService} from "./services/posts.service";

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    PostsService,
    AuthService,
    provideZoneChangeDetection({eventCoalescing: true}),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideStoreDevtools({maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode()}),
    importProvidersFrom(
      StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]),
      EffectsModule.forFeature([PostsEffects]),
      StoreModule.forFeature(COUNTER_STATE, counterReducer),
      StoreModule.forFeature(POSTS_STATE, postsReducer)
    ),
  ],

};

This is my interceptor instead:
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private authService = inject(AuthService); // Usa Store per selezionare il token

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addAuthToken(request));
  }

  addAuthToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const token = this.authService.getTokenFromLocalStorage();

    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
  }
}


you need withInterceptorsFromDi() to register the interceptors defined via HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

Thank you now I used export const authInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> => {   const authStore = inject(Store<AppState>);with provideHttpClient(withInterceptors) and now works fine

@StefanoAntonetti If my answer helped you solving the issue, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the "check" icon next to the answer. Thanks!

You have written a class-based interceptor which is provided via DI. In this case you need to explicitly enable DI-based interceptors while providing the HTTP client, using the withInterceptorsFromDi() function:
{
  providers: [
    // ...
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptorsFromDi())),
  ],
}

Alternatively, you can re-write your interceptor to to a functional interceptor instead of a class-based interceptor:
export function authInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  // ... interceptor logic
}

And then configure the interceptor in the app config like the following:
{
  providers: [
    // ...
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([authInterceptor]))),
  ],
}


But dont you think it is related to the JWT token not being properly attached to the request via the Angular interceptor? Your answer does provide clarity tho.

@D.lola No, to me the overall interceptor logic looks fine. Looks pretty much like the auth interceptor I use in production.
